# Laravel - Its Possible Add Foreign Key On Table With Data Type String With Unsigned?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

i have two table, table universitas and table fakultas

on schema table universitas like below

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('universitas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id');
            $table->string('nama_universitas');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and table fakultas like below

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('fakultas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nama_fakultas');
            $table->string('nama_universitas')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('nama_universitas')->references('id')->on('universitas');
            $table->string('keterangan');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

its possible if i use data type string and use unsigned?

when i executed with php artisan migrate, i get an Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of *unsigned* on a string makes no sense from a database perspective. The purpose of unsigned is to determine whether a numeric field can take negative values. For instance, a:

```
$table->tinyInteger('foo');
```

will create a database field that will take values between -128 and +128, whereas

```
$table->tinyInteger('foo')->unsigned();
```

will create a database field with the range 0 - 255

The important thing with your foreign keys is that the datatype of the foreign key *must* match the datatype of the primary key of the other table, whether it is a number or a string.